# uboot-menuconfig not available in make targets

Tags: linux, make, u-boot, buildroot

I'm trying to setup a custom default environment for u-boot while building an embedded Linux system with Buildroot. I was able to achieve this in u-boot standalone, but I'm unable to reproduce the same through Buildroot's Kconfig.

Running `uboot-menuconfig` fails:

```
$ make uboot-menuconfig
make: *** No rule to make target 'uboot-menuconfig'.  Stop.
```

and the `uboot-menuconfig` target is missing from the help message:

```
$ make help
Cleaning:
  clean                  - delete all files created by build
  distclean              - delete all non-source files (including .config)

Build:
  all                    - make world
  toolchain              - build toolchain
  sdk                    - build relocatable SDK

Configuration:
  menuconfig             - interactive curses-based configurator
  nconfig                - interactive ncurses-based configurator
  xconfig                - interactive Qt-based configurator
  gconfig                - interactive GTK-based configurator
  oldconfig              - resolve any unresolved symbols in .config
  syncconfig             - Same as oldconfig, but quietly, additionally update deps
  olddefconfig           - Same as syncconfig but sets new symbols to their default value
  randconfig             - New config with random answer to all options
  defconfig              - New config with default answer to all options;
                             BR2_DEFCONFIG, if set on the command line, is used as input
  savedefconfig          - Save current config to BR2_DEFCONFIG (minimal config)
  update-defconfig       - Same as savedefconfig
  allyesconfig           - New config where all options are accepted with yes
  allnoconfig            - New config where all options are answered with no
  alldefconfig           - New config where all options are set to default
  randpackageconfig      - New config with random answer to package options
  allyespackageconfig    - New config where pkg options are accepted with yes
  allnopackageconfig     - New config where package options are answered with no

Package-specific:
  <pkg>                  - Build and install <pkg> and all its dependencies
  <pkg>-source           - Only download the source files for <pkg>
  <pkg>-extract          - Extract <pkg> sources
  <pkg>-patch            - Apply patches to <pkg>
  <pkg>-depends          - Build <pkg>'s dependencies
  <pkg>-configure        - Build <pkg> up to the configure step
  <pkg>-build            - Build <pkg> up to the build step
  <pkg>-show-info        - generate info about <pkg>, as a JSON blurb
  <pkg>-show-depends     - List packages on which <pkg> depends
  <pkg>-show-rdepends    - List packages which have <pkg> as a dependency
  <pkg>-show-recursive-depends
                         - Recursively list packages on which <pkg> depends
  <pkg>-show-recursive-rdepends
                         - Recursively list packages which have <pkg> as a dependency
  <pkg>-graph-depends    - Generate a graph of <pkg>'s dependencies
  <pkg>-graph-rdepends   - Generate a graph of <pkg>'s reverse dependencies
  <pkg>-dirclean         - Remove <pkg> build directory
  <pkg>-reconfigure      - Restart the build from the configure step
  <pkg>-rebuild          - Restart the build from the build step

busybox:
  busybox-menuconfig     - Run BusyBox menuconfig

uclibc:
  uclibc-menuconfig      - Run uClibc menuconfig

linux:
  linux-menuconfig       - Run Linux kernel menuconfig
  linux-savedefconfig    - Run Linux kernel savedefconfig
  linux-update-defconfig - Save the Linux configuration to the path specified
                             by BR2_LINUX_KERNEL_CUSTOM_CONFIG_FILE

Documentation:
  manual                 - build manual in all formats
  manual-html            - build manual in HTML
  manual-split-html      - build manual in split HTML
  manual-pdf             - build manual in PDF
  manual-text            - build manual in text
  manual-epub            - build manual in ePub
  graph-build            - generate graphs of the build times
  graph-depends          - generate graph of the dependency tree
  graph-size             - generate stats of the filesystem size
  list-defconfigs        - list all defconfigs (pre-configured minimal systems)

Miscellaneous:
  source                 - download all sources needed for offline-build
  external-deps          - list external packages used
  legal-info             - generate info about license compliance
  show-info              - generate info about packages, as a JSON blurb
  printvars              - dump internal variables selected with VARS=...

  make V=0|1             - 0 => quiet build (default), 1 => verbose build
  make O=dir             - Locate all output files in "dir", including .config

For further details, see README, generate the Buildroot manual, or consult
it on-line at http://buildroot.org/docs.html
```

However u-boot is enabled and is correctly built along with kernel and file system. Is there a config option I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously there was such a config option. I was building u-boot with the legacy build system that does not include Kconfig configuration; therefore, menuconfig was not available.

To have `uboot-menuconfig` among the accepted targets I had to select `Kconfig` instead of `Legacy` in the Bootloaders -> U-Boot -> Build System menu.